# When attempting to install WhatsApp Messenger on Android-x86, I get the error: "Your device isn't compatible with this version."

Tags: android-x86

Some applications install, while others don't.  This one in particular, WhatsApp Messenger, is very important for me to get running, since my Mobile Android device needs repairs.  How can I get this installed?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do it through Google Play?

Try [direct link](http://www.whatsapp.com/download/) from whatsapp web-site.

I had the same error when I was trying to install the app from Google Play on my AVD. Perhaps following instruction will be helpful for you if you decide to run the app on the emulator.

There were my steps to install it (you already need an installed Android SDK or Bundle):

1. Download whatsapp (link is above)
2. Run your emulator
   ./LOCATION/TO/sdk/tools/emulator -avd VM_NAME_HERE -partition-size 500 -no-audio -no-boot-anim -netfast
3. Mount the storage:
   ./LOCATION/TO/sdk/tools/platform-tools/adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
4. Give permissions
   ./LOCATION/TO/sdk/tools/platform-tools/adb shell chmod 777 /system/app
5. Push the apk to the device:
   ./LOCATION/TO/sdk/tools/platform-tools/adb push /LOCATION/TO/YOUR/WHATAPP/APK/WhatsApp.apk /system/app/.

That's all